# HTML Rendering differently local vs server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having an issue developing an asp.net application. It renders content differently depending on whether it's being run in the local environment or in the server environment.

I have a custom user control that contains a label, a textbox and two buttons, one button is on either side of the text box.

When rendered locally, everything is fine. When rendered on the server, the buttons become wider and the left one partially covers over the textbox.

I believe it is not an issue with the IE version or compatibility mode, since the render will still be different regardless of if they have the same document mode.

A similar question was asked here with no concrete answer, and I have tried everything that was suggested in it: http://forums.asp.net/t/1672199.aspx?HTML+Rendering+differently+local+vs+server

Comment: Have you linked a css file to your page?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/12/pages-in-ie-render-differently-when-served-through-the-asp-net-development-server-and-production-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to physical/hard-code the width in your controls

**Example:** for a textbox, you would do this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="100%" Text='hello'/>
```